# Can I store a file (HDF5 file) in another file with serialization?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, hdf5

I have a HDF5 file and a list of objects that I need to store for saving functionality. For simplicity I want to create only one save file. Can I store H5 file, in my save file that I create with serialization (pickle) without opening H5 file.

Comment: "Can I store H5 file without ..." - Without what?

Comment: sorry there shouldn't be "without"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put several files in one by using [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) or [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html)

- for zipfile you would `write` the database files and `writestr` your `pickle.dumps`ed data.
- for tarfile you would `add` the database file and `gettarinfo`, `addfile` your `pickle.dump`ed data from a file.

I would suggest creating a zip if you do not need extended filesystem-attributes because it is a bit easier to use.

Comment: Thanks. Zipfile is exactly what I want to use.