# How can I save an object containing keras models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, save

Here is my code skeleton:

```
def build_model(x, y):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(x, y)
    return model

class MultiModel(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.model1 = build_model(x1, y1)
        self.model2 = build_model(x2, y2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # code that builds x1, x2, y1, y2
    mm = MultiModel(x1, y1, x2, y2)  # How to save mm ?
```

The issue is I don't know how to save the *mm* object that contains several Keras models.

The Keras built-in save method enables only to save Keras model, so it is unusable in that case.
The pickle module can not save *_thread.RLock objects*, so it is also unusable.

It is maybe possible to save each model independently with the Keras save method, then to regroup them and to save them as a whole. But I do not know how to proceed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are there any attributes in `mm` except `model1` and `model2` that you want to be saved?

Comment: Yes there are. They have basic types though.

Comment: Aren't you looking for a solution that bundles multiple files, i.e. `model1.h5`, `model2.h5`, ect., into one single file, say an archive?

Comment: Yes I think it would work just fine. Can I save keras model in .h5 format and other attributes as other formats ?

Comment: Well I think you can save the models using [`save()`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) method and dump the attributes by [pickling them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and then [zip them all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39386944/2099607).

Comment: Have you tried `cPickle` to store your instance of `MultiModel`?

Comment: @DareYang I have exactly the same problem. How did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 3):

As it took me a long time to find a working solution to a similar problem (pickling an object containing objects containing Keras models), I post here the solution. It is [adriangb's](https://github.com/adriangb), found in [LifeSaver](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/keras-model-pickle-able-but-tf-keras-model-not-pickle-able-34697):

```
import pickle

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize, serialize
from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import saving_utils


def unpack(model, training_config, weights):
    restored_model = deserialize(model)
    if training_config is not None:
        restored_model.compile(
            **saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(
                training_config
            )
        )
    restored_model.set_weights(weights)
    return restored_model

# Hotfix function
def make_keras_picklable():

    def __reduce__(self):
        model_metadata = saving_utils.model_metadata(self)
        training_config = model_metadata.get("training_config", None)
        model = serialize(self)
        weights = self.get_weights()
        return (unpack, (model, training_config, weights))

    cls = Model
    cls.__reduce__ = __reduce__

# Run the function
make_keras_picklable()

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=42, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='Nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Save
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

Thanks Adrian !